# How the media query elements tag works in html

Tags: css, html

The content does not display properly. IS there anything wrong with the below @media query?

```
  @media screen and (max-width:) and (orientation: portrait){
    body{
        background-color:;
    }
    h1 {
        display:block;
    }
    h1 a{
        font-size:2em;
        display: block;
        height:    number;
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I use two external css one for desktop and one for mobile plus the html reset

Comment: Consider taking a look at this: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20446/anchor-tag-inside-h1-or-h1-inside-achor-tag-which-is-better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example there is no `max-width` and `background-color` values?
Also there is a `number` instead of value for `height` property

```
// add value or remove the rule, example:
// @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait){
// @media screen and (orientation: portrait){

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    body{
        background-color: black;
    }
    h1 {
        display:block;
    }
    h1 a{
        font-size: 2em;
        display: block;
        height: 400px;

    }
}
```